# Resizing multiple objects in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, flowchart

I have a flowchart that I made in Word which is made up off different elements such as a text box within a box and lines connected to the boxes.

I want to increase the size of these elements, but doing it individual would be quite tedious. Is there a feature in Word that allows you do resize my flowchart without having the need to doing it individually and then repositioning them?

Comment: Have you grouped the objects and tried resizing the group?

Comment: I did consider that option but that means i would need to individually click on each element which is something i want to avoid because it would take too long

Comment: Is the flowchart the only thing in the document? If so, try `Ctrl` + `A` to select all. Other than that, you may not have much choice.